# How do I install 10.7 Lion on an a headless mini?

Tags: osx-lion

I used to be able to install 10.6 Server remotely via ARD (blank username, first 8 characters of the serial number as password), but the functionality seem to have been removed by Apple on 10.7 (client version, the only once that can be downloaded and burned/imaged to a dvd/usb). The installer gets an IP but a quick port scan doesn't show any open ports; any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as it's a [2009 Mac Mini or newer](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2129), you can use the [Remote Install Mac OS X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Install_Mac_OS_X) tool.  [You'll need to get it from a 10.6 installation](https://discussions.apple.com/message/17765035#17765035).